# Unable to change browser's default home page

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, malware, spyware

After installing Qvod player, my IE homepage was set to:

`http://www.hao123.com/?tn=97473572_hao_pg`

I tried to set the home page via IE settings, however it changed back to `http://www.hao123.com` again. After that, I discovered I have to check on regedit on both path

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InternetExplorer\Main and HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet\Explorer\Main
```

for `Default_Page_URL`

I found my `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` setting Default_Page_URL to `hao123.com` and I quickly changed it to blank. After this, I was able to set the IE homePage to blank but the default page to appear when i click to start up IE, was `hao123.com`!

I also checked on right click> property of my IE shortcut, no default homepage are set.

After this, I uninstalled Qvod player, and it still didn't work!

Comment: Which version did you install? You downloaded the program from the [official website](http://www.qvod.com/product/index.htm), right? The setup program will install a [browser hijacker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_hijacking) and other bloatware unless you explicitly uncheck them from the options. Try scanning your system using [Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware](https://www.malwarebytes.org/mwb-download/) and [AdwCleaner](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/), then report back.

Comment: I am facing this issue after the Qvod auto update for latest version, and it didn't request for my permission to update it.
I had scan it with `Malwarebytes` and get 98 hit of Threat Scan. But it seem didn't help.
For `AdwCleaner`, my antivirus software has detected it is a threat, so i had stop running it.

Comment: Hi, I disabled my antivirus and run the `AdwCleaner`, it seem didn't help too.

Comment: Check this question for further ideas and then report back your findings: [How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solve when I rename every `.dll` in my `Qvod directory` and restart my computer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Locate the DLL file called 'QvodAddr.dll', rename it to 'QvodAddr.dll.bak'.

Step 2:
Remove the 'http://www.hao123.com/?tn=97473572_hao_pg'
from the Internet Explorer --> Internet Options --> General (Tab) --> Home page.

Step 3:
Restart your Internet Explorer.

I use this to solve my problem. 
Hope it helps you.